# How to Use SQL on saving ConversationState and UserState Bot Framework v4

Tags: botframework

I'm currently migrating my bot framework v3 to v4.

Is there any way to store the Bot State on SQL database?

I've seen documentation on Bot State here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/azure/bot-service/migration/net-migration-quickreference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&viewFallbackFrom=azure-bot-service-3.0

But it can only saves on CosmoDB or Azure Storage. No available documentation on bot framework v4 about saving State in SQL

In my bot framework v3 I have this code which saves Bot State to SQL database:

```
var store = new SqlBotDataStore(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["statedb"].ConnectionString);          
        Conversation.UpdateContainer(
           builder =>
           {
               builder.Register(c => store)
                    .Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore)
                    .AsSelf()
                    .SingleInstance();

               builder.Register(c => new CachingBotDataStore(store,
                          CachingBotDataStoreConsistencyPolicy
                          .ETagBasedConsistency))
                          .As<IBotDataStore<BotData>>()
                          .AsSelf()
                          .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

               builder.RegisterModule(new ReflectionSurrogateModule());

               builder.RegisterModule<GlobalMessageHandlersBotModule>();
           });
```

I expect that bot framework v4 has similar functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bot Framework Community has provided EntityFramework storage for Bot Builder V4.  The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Storage.EntityFramework) and the library is available as a nuget package [Bot.Builder.Community.Storage.EntityFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bot.Builder.Community.Storage.EntityFramework/)

It is used the same way as other V4 `IStorage` providers:

```
var entityFrameworkStorage = new EntityFrameworkStorage(Config["SqlConnectionString"]);
services.AddSingleton<IStorage>(dataStore);
services.AddSingleton<UserState>();
services.AddSingleton<ConversationState>();
```

More information can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state

Comment: Do we need to some how apply a migration for this to work?

Comment: No, it should not be necessary to "provide a migration", unless you are coming from V3?.  You can find a sample project here: https://github.com/EricDahlvang/EntityFrameworkTranscriptStoreExample